# Flow of forms in Node.js and Express

Tags: node.js, express

Our lab makes many web experiments, all of which have a similar flow:

1. The user fills a form and submits. The form is validated, if it is OK then the posted values are logged and the user is sent to #2; otherwise the user is asked to fill it again.
2. The user answers a quiz. If the answers are correct then go to #3; otherwise fill again.
3. The user enters the actual experiment, which is a web-app - a chat-room, a flash game, etc. After the game is finished, go to #4.
4. The user fills another form and submits.

In the past I did this with JSP, but now we've moved on to NodeJS and Express, and I wonder if there is a general way to handle this and similar control-flows.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very general, so in general the answer is Yes - you can do all that with node and express. Just register your routes with express (e.g. using app.get(URI, func)) and serve your dynamic and static content from node. There is ample material in the web on using express.